# How to insert the new object to the map only if the object doesn't exist in the map using rust?

Tags: c++, dictionary, rust, insert

I'm transporting C++ code to rust.
Here is the original C++ code.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> m {
        { "A", 1 },
        { "B", 2 },
        { "D", 4 },
    };
    // *1
    auto r = m.equal_range("C"); // *2
    if (r.first == r.second) {
        auto const& it = r.first;
        assert(it->first == "D");
        assert(it->second == 4);
        // Let's say creating the object to insert is high cost
        // so it should be created only if the element doesn't exist.
        // Creating the object at *1 is not acceptable because if the element exists,
        // then the created object isn't userd.
        //
        // `it` is hint iterator that point to insertion position.
        // If the object to isnert has the same key as the argument of equal_range (*2)
        // the time complexity is O(1).
        m.emplace_hint(it, "C", 3); 
    }
    for (auto const& kv : m) {
        std::cout << kv.first << ":" << kv.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Runnable Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4eEZ2jY9kaOK9ru0

This is inserting if not exist pattern.

I want to archive two goals.

One is inserting the object efficiently. Searching object takes O(logN) time complexity. I want to insert the new object only if the object doesn't exist in the map. If inserting the new object from the beginning, then O(logN) additional cost is required to search inserting position.
The original C++ code uses `it` as the hint to insert the new object.

The other is creating new object only if an object that has the same key doesn't exist in the map. Because creating object requires high cost in the real case. (My example code users std::string and int value. It is just an example.)
So, I don't want to pre-create the object for insertion at *1.

I read BTreeMap document. But I couldn't find the way.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html

Is there any good way to do that ?
Or is there any non standard container(map) to support the operation that I want to do ?

Comment: Have you considered `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`?  Then it would be a matter of how good the hash function is, instead of an `O(n log n)` lookup time.

Comment: std::map::try_emplace?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , I'd like to know rust way. Not C++. The code is the original code that I want to transport to rust. BTW, lookup time is O(lon n), I think.

Comment: @Equod, good to know std::map::try_emplace. The C++ original code is the same as std::map::try_emplace. Thanks. But I want to know rust way.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo So Rust doesn't have a built-in hash table class?  This is why it isn't a good idea to do line-by-line translations from one language to another.  A faster lookup is done using hash tables with a good hash function.  The `std::map` does not use hashing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , hash or ordered (tree based) container is not essential topic in this question. If the order is important, I can't use hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want the Entry API?

In the rustification of your example, `m.entry("C")` would return an [Entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/enum.Entry.html) enum which contains the information of whether the entry is present or not. You can then either dispatch explicitly or use one of the high-level methods e.g. `BTreeMap::or_insert_with` which takes a function (and thus creates the object to insert lazily)

So the Rust version would be something along the lines of:

```rust
let mut m = BTreeMap::new();
m.insert("A", 1);
m.insert("B", 2);
m.insert("D", 4);

m.entry("C").or_insert_with(|| {
    3 // create expensive object here
});

for (k, v) in &m {
    println!("{}:{}", k, v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I found `player_stats.entry("defence").or_insert_with(random_stat_buff);` example in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html . It seems that or_insert_with() can take a function parameter. The example random_stat_buff is a function. Is random_stat_buff called only if the element doesn't exist? I guess so.

Comment: Yes. That's the entire point of it, otherwise you can just use `.or_insert` which takes an actual object to insert (and is thus better for very cheap object) (or `.or_default()` which automatically builds and inserts a default value -- assuming the value type implements `Default`).

Comment: Also note, in case you have a use for it: all of them return a mutable reference to the entry's value, either the one that was there or the one you just inserted. This is useful when you also want to update the entry unconditionally (regardless of it being an existing or new one) e.g. `m.entry(k).or_insert(0) += 1` will insert a `0` if there was no entry, then will increment the value regardless.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is perfect. or_insert_with can do a kind of lazy instantiation. It's nice.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: The downside is that now that you have tested the `Entry` API, you will despair when using any map that doesn't have it...